# How do I get <drupal-media> to appear?

Tags: media, 9

I am trying to use the Drupal Media insert button in the CKEditor5 module. (Important - the existing images were included using CKEditor4 and are inline images, not using Drupal Media.)

I upload the image I want to the Media Library and then select it in CKEditor5.

You can see that the image appears in the dialog box. But when I save nothing appears on the actual page.

[image: Showing where the Drupal media image should appear]

The HTML, where the image should appear, looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <drupal-media data-entity-type="media" data-entity-uuid="5acaee67-a8fe-4265-81d2-82099838073b" data-align="center">&nbsp;</drupal-media>
  </td>
</tr>
```

How do I get it to show? I've read everything I can find but no joy.

Comment: You have to add the button to the editor **AND** enable the CKeditor text **filter** at `/admin/config/content/formats`. Also ordering of those filters matters, if active try moving upwards or downwards

Comment: They are. The ordering does matter and it's correct  - it has to be after align and caption, I've had it at the end, and also just before "fix faulty HTML". It makes no difference.

Comment: This could also be the theme not applying text filters. Did you try to switch the theme?

Comment: Ran into the exact same issue.  Disabled all filters except "Embed media" and problem still occurs.  If you figure this out please let us know.